# Client Server mouse control via LAN

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm trying to sync the mouse events, such as mouse click and movement, on client from server (using Java socket). I just Googled and came to know about the `Robot` class, but I don't know how to use it and where to start for my scenario. Can anyone provide a useful link or tutorial for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good [*Introduction to the Java Robot Class in Java*](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2212401/Introduction-to-the-Java-Robot-Class-in-Java.htm).

Comment: Thanks trashgod, I'll check it out.